# Check if scriptlet object exist/is defined in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, portlet

File a.jsp has code:

```
<%
 Object OBJECT = smt...
%>

<jsp:include page="c.jsp"/>
```

File c.jsp has code:

```
<%
   do smth with OBJECT 
%>
```

File b.jsp has code:

```
<jsp:include page="c.jsp"/>
```

**Problem** is that b.jsp does not have code for creating/initialize a OBJECT and when workflow is such that b.jsp is supposed to be rendered there is a "OBJECT 
 cannot be resolved to a variable" error.

**How to check if OBJECT exists in c.jsp page context?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<c:if />` taglib in Liferay. At the top section of your jsp file insert this line:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Then you can use the taglib as follows:

```
<c:if test="<%= object != null %>">
    <!-- HTML elements -->
    <%
        //scriptlet
    %>
</c:if>
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that will generate same error message since you are suggesting to check if `Java object` member named OBJECT is not null within scriptlet context and in case b.jsp is used OBJECT will not be present as a member of this `Java object`